# What to say if someone is blocking your way

Tags: politeness, conversation

If you want to go into a subway entrance, but someone is blocking your way, **what should you say?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a request to that person?

Comment: Can you add more details to the post? It is likely to be closes if not. Please also add any research you have already done. Is there any reason why "someone was blocking my way to the subway" doesn't work for you?

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange!  Thank you for the question.  To improve your question, be sure to say *what you think the right answer might be* --- or *what confused you when you did your own research*.  Thanks for accepting (with a green check-mark) an answer. Keep contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just say **"Excuse me. Can you let me through?"** or **"Excuse me. Can you let me pass?"**.